# Angular jqLite: .find() won't work - does not select tags

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, jqlite

I have this unit spec in jasmine:

```
define(['common/components/directives/directives', 'angular'], function (directives, ng) {

describe('The directives module', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        ng.mock.module('directives');
    });

    describe('The tabset directive', function () {
        var scope;
        var elm;

        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
            elm =   ng.element('<tabset>' +
                            '<tab data-route="/home" data-title="Home"></tab>' +
                            '<tab data-route="/tournaments" data-title="Tournaments"></tab>' +
                            '<tab data-route="/about" data-title="About"></tab>' +
                        '</tabset>');

            var scope = $rootScope;
            $compile(elm)(scope);
            scope.$digest();
        }));

        it ('should create clickable titles', function () {
            var titles = elm.find('ul li a');

            expect(titles.length).toBe(3);
            expect(titles.eq(0).text()).toBe('Home');
            expect(titles.eq(0).text()).toBe('Tournaments');
            expect(titles.eq(0).text()).toBe('About');
        });

        //it ('should change active tab when clicked', function () {

        //});

    });
});
```

});

In the test `it ('should create clickable titles', ...` I try to use `.find()`, but the selection comes out empty: `LOG: Object{}`. This is what `elm` contains in the test:

```
LOG: Object{0: 
<ul class="nav nav-tabs ng-scope" ng-transclude="">
    <li data-ng-class="{active: active}" data-route="/home" data-title="Home" class="ng-scope">
        <a href="#/home" class="ng-binding">Home</a>                                       
    </li>
    <li data-ng-class="{active: active}" data-route="/tournaments" data-title="Tournaments" class="ng-scope">
        <a href="#/tournaments" class="ng-binding">Tournaments</a>                                 
    </li>
    <li data-ng-class="{active: active}" data-route="/about" data-title="About" class="ng-scope">                                           
        <a href="#/about" class="ng-binding">About</a>                                     
    </li>
</ul>, length: 1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `el.find()` tries to find an element in set of `el`'s children, their children etc. You're trying to find `ul` in element which is `ul` itself and contains only `li` elements. Also, you cannot use child selectors in `find`. Use chained `el.find('li').find('a')` instead.

Comment: Thank you, should have realized this.

Comment: As said in other answer, you can also search directly for `'a'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `.find` method this way. Use it like:

```
elm.find('a');
```

Or:

```
elm.find('ul').find('li').find('a');
```

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/Khp4R/2/